# Syntax of using a comparator

Tags: java, syntax, comparator, comparable

Suppose I'm trying to use a comparator object as such:

```
public static <Key> int find (Key[] a, Key key, Comparator<Key> comparator)
```

To find key in array, a.

How would I go about using comparator.

I tried `if (comparator.compare(key, a[i]) == 1)`

But this gives me an error "Comparator cannot be resolved to a type".
Sorry if this is a really dumb question.

Comment: Have you imported it?

Comment: Thank you. That fixed it. I knew it was a dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using eclipse, you would know there's a missing import because there would be a red marker on the line with the compile error, and the offending type will have a red wavy line under it.  If you see that, your first action should be to look for a [quick fix](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-quickfix-assist.htm). A missing type is easy to spot, and requires just one click to resolve.